# How to add colorbars to scatterplots created like this?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I create scatterplots with code that, in essence, goes like this

```
cmap = (matplotlib.color.LinearSegmentedColormap.
        from_list('blueWhiteRed', ['blue', 'white', 'red']))

fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=72)
ax = fig.gca()

for record in data:
    level = record.level # a float in [0.0, 1.0]
    marker = record.marker # one of 'o', 's', '^', '*', etc.
    ax.scatter(record.x, record.y, marker=marker,
               c=level, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap=cmap, **otherkwargs)

# various settings of ticks, labels, etc. omitted

canvas = matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
fig.set_canvas(canvas)
canvas.print_png('/path/to/output/fig.png')
```

My question is this:

> What do I need add to the code above to get a vertical colorbar (representing the colormap in `cmap`) along the plot's right edge?

**NOTE**: I find Matplotlib ***utterly incomprehensible***, and this goes for both its design as well as its documentation.  (Not for lack of trying: I have putting a lot of time, effort, and even some money, into it.)  So I would appreciate complete, working code (even if it's just a toy example), because most likely I won't be able to fill in omitted details or fix bugs in the code.

---

EDIT: I fixed an important omission in the "code sketch" above, namely a record-specific marker specification in each call to `ax.scatter`.  This is the reason for creating the scatterplot with multiple calls to `ax.scatter`, although, admittedly, one could at least reduce the number of calls to scatter to one per maker shape used; e.g.

```
for marker in set(record.marker for record in data):
    X, Y, COLOR = zip(*((record.x, record.y, record.level)
                        for record in data if record.marker == marker))
    ax.scatter(X, Y, marker=marker,
               c=COLOR, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap=cmap,
               **otherkwargs)
```

I tried to extend the same trick to collapse all calls to `ax.scatter` into one (by passing a sequence of markers as the `marker` argument), like this:

```
X, Y, COLOR, MARKER = zip(*((record.x, record.y, record.level, record.marker)
                            for record in data))

ax.scatter(X, Y, marker=MARKER,
           c=COLOR, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap=cmap,
           **otherkwargs)
```

...but this fails.  The error goes something like this (after pruning some long paths):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/demo.py", line 222, in <module>
    main()
  File "src/demo.py", line 91, in main
    **otherkwargs)
  File "<abbreviated-path>/matplotlib/axes.py", line 6100, in scatter
    marker_obj = mmarkers.MarkerStyle(marker)
  File "<abbreviated-path>/matplotlib/markers.py", line 113, in __init__
    self.set_marker(marker)
  File "<abbreviated-path>/matplotlib/markers.py", line 179, in set_marker
    raise ValueError('Unrecognized marker style {}'.format(marker))
ValueError: Unrecognized marker style ('^', 'o', '^', '*', 'o', 's', 'o', 'o', '^', 's', 'o', 'o', '^', '^', '*', 'o', '*', '*', 's', 's', 'o', 's', 'o', '^', 'o', 'o', '*', '^', 's', '^', '^', 's', '*')
```

AFAICT, tcaswell's recipe *requires* reducing the calls to `ax.scatter` to a single one, but this requirement appears to conflict with my absolute requirement for multiple marker shapes in the same scatterplot.

Comment: see edit and other comment.

Comment: i don't think there's a requirement for multiple marker shapes in `scatter`. just feed it a single marker for each group of data.

Comment: the requirement is mine: I require multiple marker shapes in the scatterplots I'm making.

Comment: @kjo see my response below

Comment: @kjo Sorry I was rude the other day, I was in a bad mood and your rant set me off.  Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: @tcaswell, almost, but I ran into problems with Matplotlib that I need to sort out first.  Thanks!  And sorry for my outburst.

Comment: Any progress getting matplotlib working?

Comment: @tcaswell: no, unfortunately; eventually I had to give up on Matplotlib (for this and other problems), and did what I had to do with Mathematica... :/

Comment: I'm sorry.  I wouldn't wish mathematica on anyone, even people I don't like.

Answer (score 12):

If you have to use a different marker for each set, you have to do a bit of extra work and force all of the `clims` to be the same (otherwise they default to scaling from the min/max of the `c` data per scatter plot).

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import itertools
fig = gcf()
ax = fig.gca()

# make some temorary arrays
X = []
Y = []
C = []
cb = None
# generate fake data
markers = ['','o','*','^','v']
cmin = 0
cmax = 1
for record,marker in itertools.izip(range(5),itertools.cycle(mlines.Line2D.filled_markers)):
    x = rand(50)
    y = rand(50)
    c = rand(1)[0] * np.ones(x.shape)
    if cb is None:
        s = ax.scatter(x,y,c=c,marker=markers[record],linewidths=0)
        s.set_clim([cmin,cmax])
        cb = fig.colorbar(s)
    else:
        s = ax.scatter(x,y,c=c,marker=markers[record],linewidths=0)
        s.set_clim([cmin,cmax])

cb.set_label('Cbar Label Here')
```

the`linewidths=0` sets the width of the border on the shapes, I find that for small shapes the black border can overwhelm the color of the fill.

[image: colored scatter plot]

If you only need one shape you can do this all with a single scatter plot, there is no need to make a separate one for each pass through your loop.

```
from pylab import *
fig = gcf()
ax = fig.gca()

# make some temorary arrays
X = []
Y = []
C = []
# generate fake data
for record in range(5):
    x = rand(50)
    y = rand(50)
    c = rand(1)[0] * np.ones(x.shape)
    print c
    X.append(x)
    Y.append(y)
    C.append(c)

X = np.hstack(X)
Y = np.hstack(Y)
C = np.hstack(C)
```

once you have the data all beaten down into a 1D array, make the scatter plot, and keep the returned value:

```
s = ax.scatter(X,Y,c=C)
```

You then make your color bar and pass the object returned by `scatter` as the first argument.

```
cb = plt.colorbar(s)
cb.set_label('Cbar Label Here')
```

You need do this so that the color bar knows which color map (both the map and the range) to use.

[image]

Comment: the code I posted is everything I did except for a `fig.savefig()`

Comment: one question ... what is the point of having in both conditions (`if .... else` block) the line  `s = x.scatter(x,y,c=c,marker=markers[record],linewidths=0)` ?

Answer (score 8):

I think your best bet will be to stuff your data into a pandas dataframe, and loop through all of your markers like so:

```
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

markers = ['s', 'o', '^']
records = []
for n in range(37):
    records.append([np.random.normal(), np.random.normal(), np.random.normal(), 
                    markers[np.random.randint(0, high=3)]])

records = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['x', 'y', 'z', 'marker'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for m in np.unique(records.marker):
    selector = records.marker == m
    s = ax.scatter(records[selector].x, records[selector].y, c=records[selector].z,
                   marker=m, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, 
                   vmin=records.z.min(), vmax=records.z.max())

cbar = plt.colorbar(mappable=s, ax=ax)
cbar.set_label('My Label')
```

[image: resuling graph]

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick. I'm pretty sure I grabbed this from one of the matplotlib cookbook examples a while back, but I can't seem to find it now...

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

cmap = (matplotlib.color.LinearSegmentedColormap.
        from_list('blueWhiteRed', ['blue', 'white', 'red']))

fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=72)
ax = fig.gca()

for record in data:
    level = record.level # a float in [0.0, 1.0]
    ax.scatter(record.x, record.y,
               c=level, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap=cmap, **otherkwargs)

# various settings of ticks, labels, etc. omitted

divider= make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="1%", pad=0.05)
cb = plt.colorbar(cax=cax)
cb.set_label('Cbar Label Here')

canvas = matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
fig.set_canvas(canvas)
canvas.print_png('/path/to/output/fig.png')
```

Comment: @JoshaInglis: the line `cb = plt.colorbar(cax=cax)` fails, with the error `RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).`  It may be very simple to fix this problem, but as I explained in an addition to my post, I am a complete Matplotlib dunce...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this *can* be to only plot a single scatter, which would then directly allow for a colobar to be created.
This involves putting the markers into the `PathCollection` created by the scatter a posteriori, but it can be easily placed in a function. This function comes from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52303895/4124317) on another question, but is directly applicable here.

Taking the data from @PaulH's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983289/4124317) this would look like

```
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mscatter(x,y,ax=None, m=None, **kw):
    import matplotlib.markers as mmarkers
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    sc = ax.scatter(x,y,**kw)
    if (m is not None) and (len(m)==len(x)):
        paths = []
        for marker in m:
            if isinstance(marker, mmarkers.MarkerStyle):
                marker_obj = marker
            else:
                marker_obj = mmarkers.MarkerStyle(marker)
            path = marker_obj.get_path().transformed(
                        marker_obj.get_transform())
            paths.append(path)
        sc.set_paths(paths)
    return sc


markers = ['s', 'o', '^']
records = []
for n in range(37):
    records.append([np.random.normal(), np.random.normal(), np.random.normal(), 
                    markers[np.random.randint(0, high=3)]])

records = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['x', 'y', 'z', 'marker'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = mscatter(records.x, records.y, c=records.z, m=records.marker, ax=ax)
fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be also a pretty easy solution.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8,8)) 

p = ax.scatter(x, y, c=y, cmap='cmo.deep')
fig.colorbar(p,ax=ax,orientation='vertical',label='labelname')
```